Rearranging parts of a filename in Windows 10
I have over 100 photos of deep-sky objects (galaxies, Nebulae, star clusters, etc.) taken by a Seestar "smart telescope".  The Seestar creates files starting with "Stacked_" followed by the object catalog no. then other information.
I'd like to rearrange the filenames to start with the catalog no. (examples below).  I slightly prefer a space after the catalog no. but an underscore is OK too (see alternately" below).  The "504" in the last (& newest) entry is from a software update.  It shows the number of frames that were stacked.  Older files do not have this number.
Stacked_IC 342_10.0s_IRCUT_20240313-211346.fit   
==> IC 342 Stacked_10.0s_IRCUT_20240313-211346.fit

Stacked_NGC 2403_20.0s_IRCUT_20240308-222904.fit
==> NGC 2403 Stacked_20.0s_IRCUT_20240308-222904.fit

Stacked_M 33_10.0s_IRCUT_20231230-205709.fit
==> M 33 Stacked_10.0s_IRCUT_20231230-205709.fit

Stacked_M 101_540_10.0s_IRCUT_20240406-230249.fit
==> M 101 Stacked_540_10.0s_IRCUT_20240406-230249.fit

or alternately: ==> M 101_Stacked_540_10.0s_IRCUT_20240406-230249.fit

There are derivative files with similar names except "Stacked_" is replaced by "starless_Stacked_" or "starmask_Stacked_" that I would like rearranged similiarly (i.e. catalog no. first).
I tried using PowerRename (Windows 10) with the match string "^Stacked_$_fit$" and the replace string "$2$1$3" but this did not work. I'd appreciate some help.
I also tried the example bat file in "Switching parts of a filename" (except I commented-out "@echo off" and added a pause so I could see whether it worked.  Result: "File Not Found".
If you want to see one of these photos, check out the galaxy M 33 on my Dropbox.
Thanks,
--- Fred

Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

To get you started, you would want to use PowerShell for this. You can use this to get started: get-childitem | foreach-object { write-host $_ } which will put each file in $_ as it loops and prints that to the window.

Power Rename uses Regular Expressions (if enabled). What you have is… certainly something, but not a Regular Expression.
